# Python Subprocess Opening My Pycharm Folder and Jupyter Folder Instead of Target

Tags: python, subprocess, unzip, 7zip

Hello I am attempting to unzip a folder using a python sub-process similar to the instructions detailed here:
[4th Solution Down in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603204/how-to-extract-7z-zip-file-in-python-2-7-3-version)

I have the following code:

```
Z_Location = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7zFM.exe'
Extract_File ='C:\\Users\\jnardone\\Desktop\\containszips\\myzipfile.zip'
Extract_PW = 'PASSWORD'
Extact_Folder = 'C:\\Users\\jnardone\\Desktop\\containsunzips'

Extract_Target = Z_Location + ' e ' + '"' + Extract_File + '"' + ' -p' + '"' + Extract_PW + '"' + ' -o' + '"' + Extact_Folder + '"'

subprocess.call(Extract_Target)
```

When I run this process however it just opens a 7zip window that is targeting my Pycharm file or my jupyter notebook file. See attached image:

[image]

I believe the targeting of my subprocess is off somewhere, I have tried using an os path as well, but I am unsure of syntax.

UPDATE:

I have changed the subprocess to work in my computer's directory instead of the notebook/IDE. However now I am seeing another issue of the zipped file not being unzipped, but duplicated.

```
subprocess.call(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe e C:\Users\jnardone\Desktop\folder\file.7z -pPASSWORD",cwd=r'C:\Users\jnardone\Desktop\auto_test_3')
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your 7zip isn't just opening up to the default location?

Comment: I have made an edit to force my sub process to function in the directory of my PC instead of the jupyter notebook/pycharm environment. I will update my question with the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution included the following:

1. Changing the current working directory out of the Pycharm/Jupyter directory.
2. Changing the archive target to the main folder containing the zip file, not targeting directly to the zipped file.

Hopefully this saves others some time as I was unable to find my issue though it was simple.